# Encoding issue when getting Database entries in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, laravel-5

I'am trying to get some entries from a Database which need UTF-8 encoded text. But the text gets only shown as `ã‚¹ãƒ¼ãƒ‘ãƒ¼ã‚µãƒ³ãƒ€ãƒ¼ãƒ–ãƒ¬ãƒ¼ãƒ‰`.

At the moment the method to get the stuff from my Database is the following code:

```
public function getDetails($title){
    $result = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `title` = ?', [$title]);
    return view('details', ['details' => $result]);
}
```

The code of my view is:

```
@foreach ($details as $detail)
                <li>{{ $detail->text }} </li>
@endforeach
```

I tried to override the echo function of Blade with the following stuff inside the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
```

I made sure that my documents are UTF-8 and the `<head>`of the View contains `<meta charset="utf-8">`, my db-tables are also UTF-8 and I tried to make a simple PHP-File to query the DB via `mysqli`and the results are fine. Hardwritten special chars inside the view are no problem, either.

Any other things to look after or try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hex is `C3A3 E2809A C2B9 C3A3 C692 ...`, you have "double encoding".  That is usually caused by...

- The client had characters encoded as utf8 (good); and
- `SET NAMES latin1` lied by claiming that the client had latin1 encoding; and
- The column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (good).

Had you also done `utf8_encode()` at that time?

Here's what happened.  For the first character, you had `E382B9`.  But, by saying `latin1`, that was treated as `E3 82 B9`, which in latin1 is `ã‚¹`.  Those *three* characters we sent to the table, converting on the fly to `utf8`, as indicated on the table/column definition:  `C3A3 E2809A C2B9` -- the utf8 hex for those 3 characters.

Normaly, "double encoding" 'repairs' itself upon reading.  That is the steps are reversed with *two* translations from utf8 to latin1 and you get back `ス`.

But apparently one of the translations was skipped.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+--------------
| Variable_name            | Value
+--------------------------+--------------
| character_set_client     | utf8          **
| character_set_connection | utf8          **
| character_set_database   | latin1
| character_set_filesystem | binary
| character_set_results    | utf8          **
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4
| character_set_system     | utf8
| character_sets_dir       | ...
+--------------------------+------------
```

The three `**` are set simultaneously when doing `SET NAMES utf8`.  But I think you had some mixture, possibly

```
| character_set_client     | latin1
| character_set_connection | latin1
| character_set_results    | utf8
```

Not good.

If you need to recover the data, there is code in [my lengthy charset blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

I'm sorry; I don't know what it takes for Laravel to establish all *three* settings correctly.  Perhaps you could get it to execute `SET NAMES utf8` shortly after connecting.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the double encoding out. I had done `utf8_encode();` by the way - without any success. Thank you for the interesting read and your posted article. I fixed the issue inside the database with following statement `UPDATE table SET title = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(title USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);` -- Thank you very much for helping me finding my way through this issue.

Comment: Did you also find out what to set in Laravel to prevent future occurrences?  (I need to add that to the article.)

Comment: In addition to this fix I needed to use the following syntax inside the view: `{! $result->title !}` instead of `{{ $result->title }}`, because `{{ $string }}` adds an additional `htmlspecialchars();` and will mess up the text again.

Answer (score 0):

That's Mojibake for `スーパーサンダーブレード`

Usually it happens when

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Do not use any functions in your code; it only complicates figuring out what to do.

Sorry, I do not know how to configure Laravel to use utf8.

Katakana does not need utf8mb4; I don't know if Kanji does.  So, you might consider switching MySQL settings from utf8 to utf8mb4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

   - `config/database.php` states that the connection is using `utf8`
   - `CHARACTER SET utf8` is set in the column

Comment: Let's check something else...  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` to see what hex actually was stored.  I would expect `E382B9 E383BC E38391 ...`; it it is something else, then there is a different problem.

Comment: The Hexvalue of スーパーサンダーブレード is `"HEX(title_jp)": "C3A3E2809AC2B9C3A3C692C2BCC3A3C692E28098C3A3C692C2BCC3A3E2809AC2B5C3A3C692C2B3C3A3C692E282ACC3A3C692C2BCC3A3C692E28093C3A3C692C2ACC3A3C692C2BCC3A3C692E280B0"`

Comment: (I wrote another 'answer' that happens to be better aligned with the problem.  Still, this 'answer' is a reasonable explanation of what happened, given the information initially available; so I leave it in place for other readers.)